# Vertically align input tags in css

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styling

So i have a container with a wrapper inside and inside that is a h1 tag and a form and I want to align all the input tags and the h1 tag from where the tags start and put the labels to the left of them.
Like this for example:

```
         exampleName
    name []
username []
```

Here is what I have tried

```css
.edit_profile_user_container {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.edit_profile_user_wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

.edit_profile_user_info {
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
}

.edit_profile_user_form {
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div className='edit_profile_user_container'>
  <div className='edit_profile_user_wrapper'>
    <div className='edit_profile_user_info'>
      <p>username</p>
    </div>
    <form className='edit_profile_user_form'>
      <div className='edit_profile_input_section'>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" />
      </div>
      <div className='edit_profile_input_section'>
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: IMHO you should be using a [Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) --  This way there's no special customized CSS.  The work is already done for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it, minimal markup, using `display: grid`:

```css
.form-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 10rem auto;
  grid-gap: .3rem;
}

.form-container label {
  grid-column: 1;
  text-align: right;
}

.form-container label::after {
  content: ':';
}

.form-container h1 {
  grid-area: 1/2/2/3;
}

.form-container h1 + label {
  grid-row: 2;
}

.form-container input {
  grid-column: 2;
}

.form-container label, .form-container input {
  padding: .3rem .5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class='form-container'>
  <h1>exampleName</h1>
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input id="name" />
  <label for="username">Username</label>
  <input id="username" />
</div>
```

Equivalent SCSS:

```scss
.form-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 10rem auto;
  grid-gap: .3rem;
  label {
    grid-column: 1;
    text-align: right;
    &::after {
      content: ':';
    }
  }
  h1 {
    grid-area: 1/2/2/3;
    + label {
      grid-row: 2;
    }
  }
  input {
    grid-column: 2;
  }
  & label, & input {
    padding: .3rem .5rem;
  }
}
```

Note: you can reduce the CSS by adding an empty element before the `<h1>`. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/pr2uv6hq/).